# no module named _socket en pip

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

Estaba intentando descargar la librería playsound en python usando la consola, pero me da este error:

```
C:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\Archivos pavos\Sublime Text 3>pip3 install playsound
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\desktop\archivos pavos\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\desktop\archivos pavos\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\Archivos pavos\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\desktop\archivos pavos\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\desktop\archivos pavos\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\desktop\archivos pavos\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\desktop\archivos pavos\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'
```

sublime text 3 es el archivo donde tengo instalado python. Probé a cambiar pip3 por pip pero no funcionó. Tengo windows 10 64 bit y python version 3.7. Gracias de antemano

Comment: El problema parece ser en las variables de entorno. Aunque podría funcionar bien dónde tienes los archivos de python actualmente, recomiendo que instales python (para todos los usuarios) en `C:\Python37` y verifica que, tanto el directorio base, como el directorio `site-packages` estén referenciados en la variable de entorno PATH. Puedes ver [Esta Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146296/missing-socket-after-compile-python-3-6)

Comment: @aeportugal muchas gracias, ya solucioné el problema abriendo python-3.7.4.exe y ejecutando la opción "repair".

Comment: Ese comentario, coloca abajo como respuesta y dentro de 24 horas márcala como aceptada. Estarás colaborando con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D